# Make a Soft-Body to follow path

Tags: physics, bezier-curves, constraints, path, soft-body

I am making a small tetris animation but the problem is that the blocks are not falling as they should. Sometimes they collide with the container walls and sometimes they do not land on the position the need to. I was wondering whether I can make soft bodies follow a path while taking gravity into consideration. If yes, can I make the blocks collide with the container, spin and position them where needed? When I searched for this a bit, I found out that I would have to use soft-body goal and vertex groups but I have no idea how to use them.

So can anyone please explain this to me?
Thanks.

[blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51918)

(After a lot of fiddling around, I was able to animate these four blocks but I don't think I can do this for all of them).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you go to the weight paint mode and paint a certain area that you want to animate and then in physics settings you check goal and choose the vertex group you created, you can add location/rotation/scale keyframes which will affect the vertex group only.[image: pulled drastically by keyframe]

here the object(cube) is being pulled by 2 simple keyframes

Comment: Well, I am really a beginner in animation but do you mean that I should Location Keyframe start and end of the animation? I tried it and it looks like the object is just following the keyframes and not taking in consideration the Gravity in physics. Also, the animation stops at the last keyframe and doesn't move further. I also want the blocks to bounce like in real life. A step-by-step solution or the .blend file would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: what blender version do you use? so i send the right type of file because 2.79 can't handle 2.8 files.

Comment: Thanks. it's 2.79b.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wiVI6gGV1Xi-MejeQx-7bj4l_qqXw26l for 2.79b

Comment: Well I have seen the file and it looks like the cube is not taking gravity into consideration, it is just moving linearly from one point to another. Also, the bounce doesn't seem realistic since I think the cube is starting to fall from the last keyframe and not the first.